# Vue3 reactive object not showing correct value in :rules of Vuefrom

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Here is my component for Vueform elements (Textelement, checkboxgroupelement etc)

```
<component v-for="question, i in questions" :is="`${question.type}-element`" 
:name="i" :label="question.label" 
:description="question.description"
:items="question.items" 
:key="i" 
:placeholder="question.placeholder" 
:rules="question.rule" />
```

All things are working correctly except for :rules which is for form validation.

Originally "questions" is an array of objects and computed method is as follows:

```
computed: {
    questions() {
      return this.data.questions?.map(q => { console.log(isReactive(q)); 
         return { ...q, rule: [`min:${q.minchars}`, `max:${q.maxchars}`] } 
      })
    },
  },
```

Output shows null even if max and min chars are set correctly.

[Heres an output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kKI8.png)

Please help!

I tried using reactivity on questions array so that rule gets updated , its showing updated values but in output I am getting message "must be at least null characters" issue.

Comment: Can you add the code like how you use the rules inside your VueForm elements component?